# Reading an image into an matrix of pixels in C++

Tags: c++, windows, image, winapi, image-processing

I have read in an image into a `LPPICTURE` with `OleLoadPictre` and displayed it in a window, but what I really need to do is turn the image into a matrix of pixels which I can manipulate and save back to an image file.

Using `OleLoadPicture`, I'm able to read in virtually all of the major image formats. If I could access individual pixels, I could just loop through and extract them all.

In other related questions, people have suggested using bulky libraries like OpenCV and other highly developed libraries which do everything under the sun, but I'd prefer to keep my solution as light as possible. I've already written a basic struct for my pixels and I'm happy to do the manipulation myself.

I've been looking at the ImageMagic library with the Magic++. It seems quite good, but if there is a solution just using the Windows API to extract the pixels and save the image back to an arbitrary image format, then that would be best/lightest I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OleLoadPicture` gives you an instance of `IPicture`. Use `IPicture::get_Handle` to get the `HBITMAP` held by the `IPicture` instance. Finally, use `GetDIBits` to get the pixel data.

There's sample code for doing that [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-392677.html). Translating that from MFC to plain WinAPI should get your pixel data.